# x.509 Authentication not enabled in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, ssl, certificate, x509

I am trying to enable x.509 authentication in MongoDB.
I was able to compile with ssl support and was able to connect to the db using ca signed client certificate.
However it looks like all certificates signed by the same CA can connect to the database regardless of the username set in $external database.
Is this expected behaviour?
I thought mongodb would refuse connection from certificates that are not registered in $external database.

In my config file, I have following defined.

```
net:
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: blah
    PEMKeyPassword: blah
    CAFile: blah
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Comment: This question belongs on [dba.stackexcahnge.com](http://dba.stackexcahnge.com)

Answer (score 2):

This is as expected.

Anyone that has a certificate signed by the root CA you started mongo with will be able to connect to the database. However, when you auth and take an action (say, query a collection) the  supplied cert will be checked against the $external database to see if the client has permissions to take that action.

```
db.getSiblingDB("$external").auth({ mechanism: "MONGODB-X509", user: "CN=MyCommonName,OU=MyOrgUnit,O=MyOrg,ST=Washington,C=US"})
```